# how to calculate a 2D array with numpy mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a 2 dimension array and based if the value is greater than 0 I want to do a operation (example with x+1).
In plain python something like this:

```
a = [[2,5], [4,0], [0,2]]
for x in range(3):
    for y in range(2):
        if a[x][y] > 0:
            a[x][y] = a[x][y] + 1
```

Result for a is *[[3, 6], [5, 0], [0, 3]]*. This is what I want.

Now I want to prevent the nested loop and tried with numpy something like this:

```
a = np.array([[2,5], [4,0], [0,2]])
mask = (a > 0)
a[mask] + 1
```

The result is now a 1 dimension and the shape of the array *[3 6 5 3]*. How can I do this operation and don't loose the dimension like in the plain python example before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `a` is a numpy array, you can simply do -

```
a[a>0] +=1
```

Sample run -

```
In [335]: a = np.array([[2,5], [4,0], [0,2]])

In [336]: a
Out[336]: 
array([[2, 5],
       [4, 0],
       [0, 2]])

In [337]: a[a>0] +=1

In [338]: a
Out[338]: 
array([[3, 6],
       [5, 0],
       [0, 3]])
```

Comment: Thank you! With a mask it would be a[mask] =  a[mask]+ 1 right?

Comment: @gustavgans Here `a>0` is the mask. So it's equivalent to `a[mask] += 1`. That `+=` is an in-situ change. Another more *explicit* way to put it would be as you did: `a[mask] = a[mask]+ 1`.